# How to read a CSV which has grouped data where each group has different columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning Python. In the same context, I have got an assignment to parse a CSV and compare with another which is in the same format.

CSV can be read as :

```
"first-report","10/01/2019 at  18:54:55"
"Tags Company","B2 603, Belcastel","MV Street, (near Orbis School - 2)","Pune","Maharashtra","India","1"
"James Kooney","sants_rn","Manager"
"Groups","IPs","Hosts","Hosts Matching Filters","Analysis","Date Range","Network","Tags"
"null","NONE","0","0","scans","N/A","ALL","NONE"

"Total Vulnerabilities","Avg Risk","Business Risk"
"17","2.8","14/100"

"IP","Network","Total Vulnerabilities","Security Risk"
"10.10.10.10","Global Default Network","17","2.8"

by Status
"Status","Confirmed","Potential","Total"
"New","1","3","4"
"Active","0","0","0"
"Re-Opened","0","0","0"
"Total","1","3","4"
"Fixed","0","0","0"
"Changed","1","3","4"
```

As it is portrayed in sample data, CSV doesnot have fixed columns. Data is segregated in different groups.
I want to compare the following keys from groups from the aforementioned CSV and print out the differences in a summary file wherever there is a mismatch in key-values.
E.g. Difference found at line 14, Expected "New" found "Active"

```
"Groups","IPs","Hosts","Hosts Matching Filters","Analysis","Date Range","Network","Tags"
"Total Vulnerabilities","Avg Risk","Business Risk"
"IP","Network","Total Vulnerabilities","Security Risk"
"Status","Confirmed","Potential","Total"
```

Can someone please guide me for the optimum solution.

I was struggling with finding different options but no luck so far.
My approach was using CSV.DictReader to compare each key, however, because of the variable column count, I am facing some indexing issues.

Here is the sample code which I have written.

```
    summary = open(summary, 'w')
    actualcsvdict = csv.DictReader(open(actualoutput), fieldnames=fieldnames)
    exxpectedcsvdict = csv.DictReader(open(expectedoutput), fieldnames=fieldnames)

    actualcsvrows = list(actualcsvdict)
    expectedcsvrows = list(exxpectedcsvdict)
    print(len(actualcsvrows))
    for line in range(len(actualcsvrows)):
        if actualcsvrows[line] != expectedcsvrows[line]:
            summary.write(f"\nMismatch found at line number {line + 2}\n")
            for key1 in actualcsvrows[line]:
                if actualcsvrows[line][key1] != expectedcsvrows[line][key1]:
                    summary.write(
                        f"For {key1} column, Expected value was[ {actualcsvrows[line][key1]} ] Found [ {expectedcsvrows[line][key1]} ]\n")
```

P.S. fieldnames in this case is

```
"Status","Confirmed","Potential","Total"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, you don't need to use the `DictReader` class, the normal `reader` class is enough.

```
summary = open(summary, 'w')
actualcsv = csv.reader(open(actualoutput))
exxpectedcsv = csv.reader(open(expectedoutput))

actualrows = list(actualcsv)
expectedrows = list(exxpectedcsv)
for line in range(len(actualrows)):
    if actualrows[line] != expectedrows[line]:
        summary.write(f"\nMismatch found at line number {line + 2}\n")
        for act,exp in zip(actualrows[line], expectedrows[line]):
            if act != exp:
                summary.write(f"Expected {exp}, got {act}\n")
```

But to be honest, I think your problem could get solved by the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) library, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: This seems to be working however doesn't solve my problem. Using DictReader I was able to print the column name for which difference in value is observed. This approach prints the value only, not the column name. Any clue on that?
Thanks !